# Mandarin equivalent to 話事?

Tags: mandarin, cantonese

In Cantonese, people often say 話事 to indicate someone is "the boss" (e.g., 你話事) or can decide some matter (e.g., what to eat, what to watch).

[This page](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/40399/) says the Mandarin equivalent is 作主, but 作主 feels a bit formal. Is 作主 really the right equivalent?

Comment: 在香港人说广东话“我话事”是什么意思？https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/1494056639767460219.html 最佳答案：一般来说，我话事只不过是指“由我作主”，例如去哪里吃饭，点什么菜，看什么电影等等，由我作主就是“我话事”，当然也可以说“我说了算”，例如公司老板，自然是他说了算，那就是公司是“我话事”. 还要就是“话事人”就是“头头、作主的人”

Comment: @user6065 could you post this as an answer so you can get credit? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently simply 他说的算 or nevertheless 他作主呗。

https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/97813888.html
https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/1887136042799627988.html

Answer (score 2):

Haha, in China, at home, the woman is the absolute ruler, so try 老婆!

老板 is very commonly heard for boss.

现在我是老板！

To be polite, you may address someone as 师傅, which is a kind of boss

Every 单位 will have a 领导, leader, boss

'boss people around' 对某人呼来唤去

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I don't hear 作主 very often and probably only in movies. 
老板 is common and is what the English word "boss" means, so basically it's an employer. 
经理 is a manager.
To answer your actual question, 作主 does describe somebody who makes decisions, but not really in a business or work setting. An example phrase could be “一切由自己作主” (yi2 qie4 you2 zi4 ji3 zuo4 zhu3). This means to be your own boss, or being independent.

Answer (score 2):

I hear 作主 enough to not think of it as particularly formal, no more than 老板; BUT it definitely isn't the most colloquial form.

[他]说的算话 is one option you could consider, and close in form to the Cantonese 話事.

Comment: How does `他说的算话` compare to `他说了算`? The latter feels a bit smoother, but are you saying it's not a common phrasing? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Crashalot 他说了算 literally means "What he says, counts" and is a common phrasing in Mandarin.  I understand it to mean "His words count", and sometimes with a subtle hint of "... while mine doesn't".  Funny enough, a quick search suggests [a movie](https://movie.douban.com/subject/1294409/) of similar name.

Comment: @FrenzyLi thanks! so which is the preferred phrasing: 他说了算 or 他说的算话?

Comment: @Crashalot 他说了算 = His words matters/counts (probably with a subtle hint that mine doesn't). I would also use 他说的算.  I have never encountered 他说的算话 before this post---I have no trouble understanding it though I subjectively feel that it is contrived. Another example: 他说了才算 Only his words matter/count.